# option to parallel build an app

Tags: debian, compiling, parallelism

These are the debian/rules from an app. called [i-nex](https://github.com/i-nex/I-Nex). It is a CPU-Z alternative for GNU/Linux and has a debian sub-directory having the following files -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/I-Nex] - [4454]
└─[$] ll -r debian

-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish   296 2016-11-13 02:12 i-nex-library.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish    93 2016-11-13 02:12 gbp.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 16588 2016-11-13 02:12 copyright
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 14328 2016-11-13 02:12 changelog
drwxr-xr-x 2 shirish shirish  4096 2016-11-13 02:12 source
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shirish shirish   384 2016-11-13 02:12 rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish    63 2016-11-13 02:12 manpages
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish   110 2016-11-13 02:12 i-nex.triggers
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish  6535 2016-11-13 02:12 i-nex.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish  1408 2016-11-13 03:16 control
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish     2 2016-11-13 03:16 compat
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish     6 2016-11-13 03:17 debhelper-build-stamp
drwxr-xr-x 5 shirish shirish  4096 2016-11-13 03:18 i-nex
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish    62 2016-11-13 03:19 i-nex.substvars
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish    91 2016-11-13 03:19 files
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish   455 2016-11-13 03:19 i-nex.debhelper.log
```

I run the following two commands and a debian package comes at the end -

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules build 
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

From the above listing it is obvious that at the end back-end it is debhelper which is doing the build process from the timestamp as well as build log. This is also confirmed by running

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
```

where debian sub-directory gets rid of all the debhelper entries.

Now this is the debian/rules as can be seen -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/I-Nex] - [4453]
└─[$] cat debian/rules

#!/usr/bin/make -f
LSB_CS =        $(shell lsb_release -cs)

ifeq ($(LSB_CS),lucid)
COMPRESSION =       -- -z9 -Zgzip
else
COMPRESSION =       -- -z9 -Zxz
endif
override_dh_autoreconf:
    cd I-Nex && autoreconf -i
override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure --sourcedirectory=I-Nex
override_dh_builddeb:
    dh_builddeb $(COMPRESSION)
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
%:
    dh $@  --with autoreconf
```

Now according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337093/how-to-run-parallel-make-with-debuild), it seems the only thing to change is the last line -

```
dh $@  --with autoreconf
```

with

```
dh $@ --parallel --with autoreconf
```

this is assuming of course, that there no missing dependencies while compiling parallelly. Am I missing something ?

JFR there are [two](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738266) [RFP's](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745049) in Debian for the package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, in compatibility level 9,

```
dh $@ --parallel --with autoreconf
```

is sufficient to enable parallel builds. Note that "missing dependencies" for parallel builds refers to target dependencies in upstream build rules (`Makefile` etc.), not package dependencies.

With compatibility level 10, the two options above are enabled by default, so

```
dh $@
```

is sufficient to enable parallel builds with `autoreconf`.

The `dh` and `debhelper` manpages have all the details.